# Crashlytics and Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

For some reason I can't setup Crashlytics with freshly created Xcode 10 project. After installing Fabric and Crashlytics pods and creating "Run script" build phase, Fabric Mac app asks to build the project. I've tried building it, cleaning and building again, building it using older version of Xcode (9.4.1), installing Crashlytics manually (without Cocoapods), but still no result - Fabric Mac app still asks to build the project.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

PS: I've also tried adding input file (`$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)`), but still no result

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "Fabric mac app still asks to build the project"?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Try enabling debug mode to see if that gets around the issue - // Objective-C
[[Fabric sharedSDK] setDebug: YES];
[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];

// Swift
Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the problem by going into Build Settings, changing Debug Information Format from "DWARF" to "DWARF with dSYM File" and building the project again.

Comment: Works , Fabric should make note on this .